# ASP.NET returns always error when configured with SSL/TLS certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, iis, asp.net

I've configured ASP.NET Core Web API on IIS and added a Let's Encrypt certificate. I've added that same cert. to two websites ( within the same domain )
One is the API and another is the Angular front-end.
I can login to the Angular platform, but ALL other requests return "500 Internal error" without further explanation.

All requests work great on Postman

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is apreciated

startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        myConfig = Configuration["Origin"];
        var config = Configuration.GetSection("JWTConfig").Get<JWTConfig>();
        JWTSecret = config.JWTSecret;
    }

    private readonly StartupSettings _startupSettings;
    private AppSettings _appSettings;

    public Startup(IOptions<StartupSettings> startupSettings, IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _startupSettings = startupSettings.Value;
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {


        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings"));
        services.Configure<AppSettingsAnex>(Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseAnexSettings"));
        services.Configure<StartupSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));
        services.Configure<IISOptions>(o =>
        {
            o.ForwardClientCertificate = false;
        });

        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(  IApplicationBuilder app, 
                            IHostingEnvironment env, 
                            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
                            IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings,
                            IMemoryCache cache
                            ) {
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;

        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Trace);

        app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials()
        );
      if (env.IsDevelopment()) {  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseUserTokenMiddleware(); // Middleware que gere a token / sessão dos pedidos http
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

[IIS configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p5r3.jpg)

[Browser console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM1SP.jpg)

**Note** Chrome shouts out some exception about SPDY error (net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR). Went [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/3ej5ua/err_spdy_protocol_error/) but nothing solved

Comment: Firstly, if you use certs on multiple domains, you need to check the box in your IIS configuration (In screenshot above). Secondly i'd recommend turning on debug messages in your web.config, it will tell you what is wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5

Comment: See in IIS log (HTTP subcode + win32 errors are there) or event log what's causing the 500.